# i want to access value of one child component in another child component in react

Tags: reactjs

The below is App.js file

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css'
import InputComponent from "./components/InputComponent";
import ResultComponent from "./components/ResultComponent";


class App extends Component {
  render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <InputComponent />
                <ResultComponent/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The below is InputComponent

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
class InputComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            owner : "",
            repo : "",
        }
    }

    //here event.target.value is setting value of target to this owner
    ownerName = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            owner:event.target.value
        })
    }

    //here event.target.value is setting value of target to this repo
    repoName = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            repo:event.target.value
        })
    }




    render(){
        //let submit = this.props;
        let {items} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <p>The current Owner is {this.state.owner} and the current Repo is {this.state.repo}</p>
                <input type='text' onChange={this.ownerName} value={this.state.owner} placeholder='Enter Username' className='inputFields'/>
                <br/>
                <input type='text' onChange={this.repoName} value={this.state.repo} placeholder='enter Repository' className='inputFields'/>
                <br/>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default InputComponent;
```

The below is Result Component

```
import React,{Component} from "react"
import axios from "axios";

class ResultComponent extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            items: []
        }
        this.apiFetch=this.apiFetch.bind(this)
    }

    apiFetch = () => {
        axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${this.props.owner}/${this.props.repo}/issues`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                this.setState({
                    items:response.data,

                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }


    render(){
        let {items} = this.state;
        return(
            <div className='submit'>
                <button onClick={this.apiFetch}>Fetch Results</button>
                <ul>
                    {items.map(item=>(
                            <li key={item.id}>
                                Issue-title: {item.title}
                            </li>
                        )
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ResultComponent
```

I want to access the value of owner,repo from InputComponent in ResultComponent in my URL part
'''axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${this.props.owner}/${this.props.repo}/issues`)'''
but not able to do so, can anyone help me what i am doing wrong. I am not able to figure out the issue I am new to React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are the options for passing data between react components :

1. From Parent to Child using Props
2. From Child to Parent using Callbacks
3. Between Siblings :
        (i) Combine above two methods
        (ii) Using Redux
        (iii) Using React’s Context API
4. Use design pattern like HOC or render Props for sharing code between React components (render code abstrait => good practice for reusable)

In your case, it's good pratice with the design pattern render Props. For example, I propose an example of codes :

```
class InputComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      owner : "",
      repo : "",
    }
  }

  //here event.target.value is setting value of target to this owner
  ownerName = (event) => {
      this.setState({
          owner:event.target.value
      })
  }

 //here event.target.value is setting value of target to this repo
  repoName = (event) => {
      this.setState({
          repo:event.target.value
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <input type='text' onChange={this.ownerName} value={this.state.owner} placeholder='Enter Username' className='inputFields'/>

        {/*
          use the `render` prop to dynamically determine what to render.
        */}
        {this.props.render(this.state)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class WithInputComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InputComponent render={dataInput => (
          <ResultComponent  dataInput={dataInput} />
        )}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here the links in more details :

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf

Comment: @AnirudhSingla : If it help you, please vote +1 for my response :D 
You're welcome

Comment: How to give +1 I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are three answers to this question:

1. You should set your state as high on the DOM tree as you can so that
   you can pass the values down to siblings. In simple terms, if state
   is set by the parent of the two, you can just ask for state from the
   parent and you're done.
2. You can use a state management system like Redux, which effectively
   does the same thing behind the scenes.
3. You can use refs, but you probably shouldn't so ignore that.

If I were you, I would just bring my state up to App.js, modify it from InputComponent, and pass that modified state down to ResultComponent.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state = {//initial values}
  }

  changeSomething() {
      // function that changes your state's values
  }
  render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <InputComponent aFunctionProp={changeSomething} />
                <ResultComponent inputVals={this.state}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Check this out as well:
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Remember that when you pass down props through your component, you refer to them by their prop name, not by the value you pass in. So in InputComponent, you'll be looking for aFunctionProp() rather than changeSomething(). That was pretty confusing to me when I first learned React.

Comment: can you want me to access these value in App.js file

Comment: In the Above Approach we are making the changes in state value in App.js file and then passing those state values to the result Component via this
```<ResultComponent inputVals={this.state}/>```

Comment: Its like i am implementing My Input Component in App.js file