# React Update Child's state from Parents Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When `chartValue: true` an object appears on the chart.

```
class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

     this.state = {
       chartValue: false,
     };
   }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      chartValue: nextProps.chartValue
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.chartValue}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to change the value to true via a button in my app component.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = ({
       chartValue: false,
    });
  }

  callChartValue() {
    this.setState({
      chartValue: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={this.callChartValue}>call</button>
         <Chart chartValue={this.state.chartValue} />
       </div>
    )}
  }
}
```

It seems like changing the state in my App.js doesnt translate to a change in the state of the chart component. I've tried without using componentWillReceiveProps but it hasn't worked either.

Comment: Your button doesn't work. onClick is supposed to be a function reference, not a string. Also why do you need to have the state inside `Chart`, if you can just use `this.props.chartValue` ?

Comment: You're right I changed it in the edit. Well I'm new to React, not sure if I did it right. In reality the code is alot more complex, `this.props.chartValue` is native to `Chart` and needs to be changed remotely

Comment: You could view my answer for passing data between react components : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59778872/4386148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main issues in your code:

#### 1. You should bind your methods

Otherwise, you won't have access to `this` inside them.

```
constructor(props) {

  ...

  // Add this to your constructor
  this.callChartValue = this.callChartValue.bind(this);

  ... 
}
```

#### 2. You shouldn't use strings for referencing the methods

```
render() {
  return (

    ...

     // Wrong
     <button onClick="callChartValue">call</button>

     // Right
     <button onClick={this.callChartValue}>call</button>

    ...

)}
```

Comment: Should I add in the binding you posted or switch out my `React.createRef()`? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I just removed the **reference** word to avoid misunderstanding. Cheers.